# How to highlight nested object hits in Elasticsearch v5

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get highlighting returned on hits from nested queries. According to the documentation, this is possible. The documentation says:

> The parent/child and nested features allow the return of documents that have matches in a different scope. In the nested case, documents are returned based on matches in nested inner objects.
>   The inner hits feature returns per search hit in the search response additional nested hits that caused a search hit to match in a different scope.
>   Inner hits can be used by defining an inner_hits definition on a nested, has_child or has_parent query and filter.
>   Inner hits also supports the following per document features:
>
> > 'Highlighting', 'Explain Source', 'filtering', 'Script fields', 'Doc value', 'fields', 'Include versions'.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits

I am however unable to get this working based on the below mapping and query. Can anyone explain why and where I am going wrong?

NOTE: I am specifically referring to nested types and not parent_child.

I've found it only works when changing referenceIdValue and ReferenceIdType from keyword to text  but obviously this is not what I want. ES Documentation says:

> "The field name supports wildcard notation. For example, using comment_* will cause all text and keyword fields (and string from versions before 5.0) that match the expression to be highlighted. Note that all other fields will not be highlighted." https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#_highlight_query I'm thinking this may be a bug?

Many thanks.

Mapping:

```
{
"entity": {
    "dynamic_templates": [{
        "catch_all": {
            "match_mapping_type": "*",
            "mapping": {
                "type": "text",
                "store": true,
                "analyzer": "phonetic_index",
                "search_analyzer": "phonetic_query"
            }
        }
    }],
    "_all": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": {
        "entityName": {
            "type": "text",
            "store": true,
            "analyzer": "indexed_index",
            "search_analyzer": "indexed_query",
        "referenceIds": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "referenceIdValue": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "norms": true,
                    "store": true
                },
                "referenceIdType": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "store": true,
                    "norms": true
                }
            }
        },
        "isPublished": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "store": true
        }
    }
}
}
```

Query:

```
curl -XGET "127.0.0.1:9200/test/entity/_search?pretty" -d"
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": {
            "term": {
                "isPublished": "true"
            }
        },
        "must": [
            [{
                "nested": {
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                [{
                                    "term": {
                                        "referenceIds.referenceIdValue": "123456"
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    "term": {
                                        "referenceIds.referenceIdType": "ENCO"
                                    }
                                }]
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "inner_hits": {
                        "highlight": {
                            "fields": {
                                "referenceIds.referenceIdValue": {},
                                "referenceIds.referenceIdType": {}
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "referenceIds"
                }
            }]
        ]
    }
}
}"
```

result:

```
{
"took": 99,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 14.319202,
    "hits": [{
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "entity",
        "_id": "3423631",
        "_score": 14.319202,
        "_source": {
            "entityName": "Test Entity",
            "referenceIds": [{
                "referenceIdValue": "AAAABBBB",
                "referenceIdType": "SULA"
            }, {
                "referenceIdValue": "123456",
                "referenceIdType": "ENCO"
            }]
        },
        "inner_hits": {
            "referenceIds": {
                "hits": {
                    "total": 1,
                    "max_score": 14.319202,
                    "hits": [{
                        "_nested": {
                            "field": "referenceIds",
                            "offset": 3
                        },
                        "_score": 14.319202,
                        "_source": {
                            "referenceIdValue": "123456",
                            "referenceIdType": "ENCO"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because in the highlighting part of your query you need to set the path relative to the nested document.
Try this:

```
                "inner_hits": {
                    "highlight": {
                        "fields": {
                            "referenceIdValue": {},
                            "referenceIdType": {}
                        }
                    }
                },
```